# How to get total Hard Disk size using Win32 ManagementObjects while ignoring USB drives?

Tags: c#, winapi

**Background:** I created an app for our unit's Help Desk that grabs computer information for an asset database. Recently someone doing inventory said that a user had a USB external hard drive connected and that my app was including it in the total hard drive space.

**How do I get the total hard drive size using Win32 ManagementObjects while ignoring external/USB devices?**

I'm willing to use another `Win32ManagementObjects` items such as `Win32_PhysicalMedia`, `Win32_LogicalDisk`, or `Win32_DiskPartition`, but:

- I'm only interested in the total internal storage (don't actually care about partitions or logical drives)
- I'm more interested in figuring out what the bug is in the code below

Here's what I have:

```
long totalSize = 0;
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32ManagementObjects.Win32_DiskDrive");
// there may be multiple hard drives, so loop through them all
foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
{
    /*
     * I assume this is where the problem is. I check that the drive type
     * includes "FIXED HARD DISK" (see reference link below)
     */
    mediaType = mo.Properties["MediaType"].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
    if (mediaType.IndexOf("FIXED HARD DISK") >= 0)
    {
        totalSize += Convert.ToInt64(mo.Properties["Size"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Could this particular USB drive just be reporting bad information to the operating system? Is that possible? It's basically impossible for me to debug since the user's computer is off-site.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I can get the totalsize of my fixed disks excluding ones connected through USB with this code

```
long totalSize = 0;
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
// there may be multiple hard drives, so loop through them all
foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
{
    if (mo.Properties["InterfaceType"].Value.ToString() != "USB")
    {
        totalSize += Convert.ToInt64(mo.Properties["Size"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Trying your code I receieved a NullReferenceException when reading the value of the property MediaType.ToString(), so, I assume that this property is not always set. Probably you could try to work around the NullReference adding  `string.IsNullOrEmpty` before checking for "FIXED HARD DISK", but I have no certainity that this property is never null on a fixed disk.

By the way, using `Win32ManagementObjects.Win32_DiskDrive` gives me a `ManagementException InvalidQuery` I have to remove the `Win32ManagementObjects` string and leave only `Win32_DiskDrive`

Comment: Sorry. Since I wasn't getting an error, but more of a "false positive", I removed some of my error checking code to make it more readable.

Comment: I wonder what interface is reported for "USB attached SCSI" (greatly reduced protocol overhead compared to USB mass storage)

Comment: And of course, this doesn't help with identification of other external drives, such as FireWire and eSATA.  (Also Thunderbolt, perhaps?)  The "removal policy" mentioned by IInspectable is the better approach.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am not sure about those drive types you have listed. Sure [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx) about `InterfaceType` don't mention these types between the allowed ones. It will be a problem if they are not in the USB list but in the eventual case it need to be tested and add another if to exclude them. The Interface you have mentioned is available for C# projects or need interop?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the classic Win32 function `GetDriveType()` and check for `DRIVE_REMOVABLE` and `DRIVE_FIXED`.

Comment: `DRIVE_REMOVABLE` is for drives with removable media, not removable drives.  Back in the day it applies to floppies and Zip disks, now it's card readers (CompactFlash, MMC, SD, etc).

Comment: Straight from [GetDriveType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939.aspx): *"To determine whether a drive is a USB-type drive, call [**SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff551967.aspx) and specify the **SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY** property."*

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes that's more appropriate.  But I personally have no idea how to check it via WMI.